# TrivialDuration of miniprofiler

Tags: miniprofiler

Can we reduce the time for TrivialDurationThresholdMilliseconds using miniprofiler  tool as this code is not showing any effects written inside global.asax.cs

private void StartProfiler()

```
    {
       MiniProfiler.Start();
       MiniProfiler.Settings.TrivialDurationThresholdMilliseconds = 0.01M;
    }
```

and calling StartProfiler() method inside Application_BeginRequest

Comment: In the source code, the term "TrivialDurationThresholdMilliseconds" only appears in its definition and it is never used.

Answer (score 0):

As Burkay mentioned in his comment, the TrivialDurationThresholdMilliseconds setting does not appear to be used; so requests of less than 20ms should be recorded and displayed.

If you want to limit only record requests within a range of times you could implement something like this (typically in the Application_EndRequest method of the global.asax.cs)

```
if (MiniProfiler.Current != null)
{
    decimal minimumMillisecondsToRecord = 0.1m;
    decimal maximumMillisecondsToRecord = 5.1m;

    var durationOfProfiling = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() - MiniProfiler.Current.Started;
    if (durationOfProfiling.Milliseconds >= minimumMillisecondsToRecord
        && durationOfProfiling.Milliseconds <= maximumMillisecondsToRecord)
    {
        MiniProfiler.Stop(discardResults: false);
    }
    else
    {
        MiniProfiler.Stop(discardResults: true);
    }
}
```